# Convenient way to show touch highlight when clicking Button in Android

Tags: android, button

In iOS, one code line is enough to have button show touch highlight: yourButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;

In Android, selector could be used. However, it's quite tedious. For example, if there're 100 button icons in my app, I have to prepare at least 200 button icons: 100 for normal and 100 for highlighted.

Is there any convenient/simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Ripple Effect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect) to show touch effect

Answer (score 0):

Create a single selector, and use that as a background for all your views (this doesn't need to be created for each button individually, you can apply the same one universally).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

This can be applied universally to ALL your buttons like this:

```
<Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@color/button_selector" />
```

There is a new Ripple response, but this is available for Android 5.0 devices plus (there probably is a 3rd party library on GitHub allowing this to work on earlier OSes)